# sed + add last word on each string only if word not appears

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have the following file:

```
linuxA.mtt.corp
linux3V
linux4B
linux2A
linux5v.mtt.corp
```

how to add the `.mtt.corp` on each string that not have this word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite simple with `sed`:

```
sed -e '/\.mtt\.corp$/!s/$/.mtt.corp/' <file
```

That does `s`ubstitute end of line with `.mtt.corp` on each line which does not end with that string.

Answer (score 1):

A perl solution:

```
$ perl -lpe '$_ .= ".mtt.corp" if !/\.mtt\.corp$/' file
linuxA.mtt.corp
linux3V.mtt.corp
linux4B.mtt.corp
linux2A.mtt.corp
linux5v.mtt.corp
```

The `-p` makes `perl` print each line of the input file after applying the script given by `-e` and the `-l` removes trailing newlines from each input line and adds one to each `print` call. The `$_` variable is the current line. So this will add `mtt.corp` to the line if it doesn't match it already.

An awk solution:

```
$ awk '!/\.mtt\.corp$/{$0=$0".mtt.corp"}1;' file
linuxA.mtt.corp
linux3V.mtt.corp
linux4B.mtt.corp
linux2A.mtt.corp
linux5v.mtt.corp
```

The same idea. `.mtt.corp` is added to any lines (`$0`) that don't end with it and each line is printed (`1;`).